# How to edit Package.swift Manifest in my own published Swift Package?

Tags: swift, xcode, package, manifest

I've created a new package in Xcode. I was able to edit the Package.swift manifest file, modifying minimum os versions etc.

I pushed it to GitHub, but now I can't edit the Package.swift file. Even though I'm still in the package editor (this is before importing it into any projects).

I can view the Package.swift in the Xcode editor, but not's not editable. It doesn't even appear with Swift syntax colouring.

I can edit the file in an external editor, and then push the changes to GitHub.

But it seems Xcode doesn't know that I'm the owner of this package?

Is there any way I can get back to editing the Swift.package file in Xcode? Editing it in Xcode provided all kinds of autocomplete for platforms and versions etc, so editing it in an external editor is not ideal.

Edit: Here's the exact steps to reproduce:

1. Create new package project (with local git repo).
2. In the Source Control navigator, Repositories tab, right click Remotes > New "TestPackage" Remote... For your GitHub account, leave everything the default, except select Private visibility. Click create.
3. Make ANY change to the Package.swift (like modifying a comment within the Package() initializer as in the example below).
4. Select menu Source Control > Commit... (Don't actually commit, you can cancel out, the damage is done.)

At this point you'll notice your Package.swift loses its syntax colouring and it is no longer editable in Xcode.

Here's the contents of the Package.swift:

```
// swift-tools-version:5.5
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "TestPackage",
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages. ===You can make a test edit to this comment===
        .library(
            name: "TestPackage",
            targets: ["TestPackage"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "TestPackage",
            dependencies: []),
        .testTarget(
            name: "TestPackageTests",
            dependencies: ["TestPackage"]),
    ]
)
```

Comment: You have to edit the Swift Package itself. Navigate to the Swift Package in Finder and open the Package.swift file in Xcode.

Comment: @dasdom I'm doing that. I haven't imported the package yet at all. Updated my question to clarify this.

Comment: This is an odd experience. In 10 years, I've never encountered this (except for situations like dasdom mentioned in the comment above)

I would recommend to clear the Derived Data folder, clean the build folder, restart XCode and check what command line tools for Xcode are in use.

Comment: @Jake, I've cleared Derived Data, build folder, restarted, etc numerous times. Try it yourself. Create a new package, can edit the manifest. Create a new remote in Xcode, pushing it to GH, can no longer edit Package.swift. Same behaviour in Xcode 13.2 and 13.2.1 ‍♂️

Comment: It could be that there is an issue with the package.swift file as well. I've had that happen

Comment: Can you share the contents of that package file

Comment: @Jake Added detailed steps to reproduce (in about 2min). Does it happen for you? Is it a bug I should file a Radar for, or do I have something misconfigured?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen too. This worked for me:

- In the Project Navigator, right-click on `Package.swift` and choose `Open As > Source Code`

No idea why the file gets "locked" in the first place, but this unlocks it for me, at least in Xcode 13.4.